# google places api visit duration - is it possible?

Tags: python, api, google-places-api, google-places

Does anyone happen to know if Google Places API allows to get the average visit duration? Sometimes when you Google a business, it gives you that saying "People typically spend here 15 minutes". I don't see this anywhere on the API sadly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in the API, please consider [filing a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).